# Eclipse SVN Subclipse Tortoise Force Lock

Tags: eclipse, locking, tortoisesvn, subclipse

Is it possible to force the user to lock a file in eclipse before they edit anything?  I am using subclipse with tortoise svn.

Comment: I was hoping to recreate what Visual Studio does with Visual Source Safe.  Whenever you try to edit a file it pauses and tries to check out a file.  If there is a new file available it will ask you if you want to pull that file from the source control.  While you have this file checked out no one else can edit their's unless they disconnect from the source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this functionality for your entire project open up the root directory of your project in your file explorer.

1. Right-Click--> Properties -->
   Subversion Tab --> Properties... --> New
2. Choose svn:needs-lock
3. Check apply property recursively
4. Click Ok

Now subclipse with force you to get a lock before editing a file.